# WMI event when App-V application is started/stopped

Tags: wmi, microsoft-virtualization

Is there a WMI event you can subscribe to that will fire when a virtualized application (App-V) is started or stopped?

I need to monitor the currently running applications on the App-V client, and preferably, I'd like to avoid constant polling.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be use [Win32_ProcessTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394377%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to request a notification whenever the App-V bubble process is started/stopped.